# App Scripts : Function that returns combinations of characteres based on the positions of the first 3 largest values of an Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, combinations, permutation

I'm working with Google App Scripts, I need a function that **based on the first 3 largest values** of an Array of length 6 (range values from 1 to 20) **returns an Array where every element is a String of a combination of characters based on the positions of those 3 values**. While I have accomplished the initial process (in a very inefficient way) I am having trouble with special cases where there are repeated values that can generate multiple combinations.

Example of the structure:

outcomes_based_on_position = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

Where==> A for position 0; B for position 1; C for position 2 and so on.

array1 = [1,   6,    5,    4,    2,   3];

expected_result_from_the_function: ["BCD"]

**what i'm having trouble with:**

array2 = [1,   4,    5,    4,    4,   3];

expected_result_from_the_function: ["CBD","CDB", "CBE","CEB", "CDE", "CED"]

I have tried this (This code is snippet in a javascript console, given the similarities with App Scripts, in order to print the results; if you try this in App Script please change Writing into the console from "console.log()" to "Logger.log()"  :

```js
function fCombination(targetArray){
  var arrayResults = [];
  var resultStr = "";
  var positions = [];
  var analysis = [...targetArray];
  analysis.sort(descOrder);
  for (var i=0; i<=2; i++){
    var verifyCase = true;
    for (var count=0; count<=5;count++){
      if(positions[0]==count || positions[1]==count) {           
      //The position that was already taken into account is skipped
        continue;
      }else if ((analysis[i]==targetArray[count]) && (verifyCase)){
        switch (count){
          case 0: resultStr = resultStr+"A"; break;
          case 1: resultStr = resultStr+"B"; break;
          case 2: resultStr = resultStr+"C"; break;
          case 3: resultStr = resultStr+"D"; break;
          case 4: resultStr = resultStr+"E"; break;
          case 5: resultStr = resultStr+"F"; break;
        } 
        verifyCase = false;
        positions.push(count);
      } 
    }
  }
  switch (true){
    case (analysis[1]==analysis[2]): arrayResults=[resultStr, resultStr[0]+resultStr[2]+resultStr[1]]; break;
    case (analysis[0]==analysis[1]): arrayResults=[resultStr, resultStr[1]+resultStr[0]+resultStr[2]]; break;
    default: arrayResults=[resultStr];
  }
  return arrayResults;
}

function descOrder(element1, element2) {
  if(element1 > element2)
    return -1; //Sort element1 before element2
  if(element1 < element2)
    return 1;  //Sort element1 after element2
  return 0;    //Don't change the positions of element1 and element2
}


//Test, Examples
var targetArray1 = [1,2,15,14,12,10];
var targetArray2 = [1,2,15,14,14,10];
var targetArray3 = [1,2,15,15,14,13];
var expectedResult1 = fCombination(targetArray1);
var expectedResult2 = fCombination(targetArray2);
var expectedResult3 = fCombination(targetArray3);
console.log(expectedResult1);
console.log(expectedResult2);
console.log(expectedResult3);

//Other posible case = [1,2,15,14,13,13]
//Expected output: ["CDE", "CDF"]
//Other posible case = [1,2,15,14,14,14]
//Expected output: ["CDE", "CDE", "CDF", "CFD","CEF", "CFE"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. There is no need to change console.log to Logger.log in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

Your combinations are inconsistent. In the case of [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15], you want every combination of same values. But in your other example [1, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3], you want:

["CBD", "CDB", "CBE","CEB", "CDE", "CED"];

but the full list of combinations is:

[
'CED', 'CDE', 'ECD', 'EDC',
'DCE', 'DEC', 'EED', 'EDE',
'EED', 'EDE', 'DEE', 'DEE',
'DED', 'DDE', 'EDD', 'EDD',
'DDE', 'DED', 'BED', 'BDE',
'EBD', 'EDB', 'DBE', 'DEB',
'FED', 'FDE', 'EFD', 'EDF',
'DFE', 'DEF'
];

Even if you want to keep the first element in the first position only, which seems to be an implicit requirement of yours, then the combinations would be this:

[
'CED', 'CDE', 'CEB',
'CBE', 'CEF', 'CFE',
'CDB', 'CBD', 'CDF',
'CFD', 'CBF', 'CFB'
];

But in the title, you say you want **all possible combinations**. I have to assume you mean in the mathematical sense, but that's not what your test cases do. So it's not clear to people reading your explanation what you want your algorithm to do.

But here are two implementations, the first creates every combination, the second creates every combination but doesn't alter the position of the 1st element.

```
const A_CHAR_CODE = 65;
let toChar = (num) => String.fromCharCode(A_CHAR_CODE + num);

const getIndices = (sorted, indices, combo) => {
    let next = sorted.pop();
    let lastIndex = -1;
    let lastNumber = combo[lastIndex];
    do {
        indices.push(next.i);
        lastNumber = combo[next.i];
        next = sorted.pop();
    } while (sorted.length && next.x == lastNumber);
    sorted.push(next);
}

let createSorted = (combo) => {
    return combo.map((x, i) => ({x, i})).sort((el1, el2) => {
        if (el1.x > el2.x) return 1;
        if (el1.x < el2.x) return -1;
    });
}

// Permutes last 2
function fCombination1(combo) {
    let sorted = createSorted(combo);
    let indices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        getIndices(sorted, indices, combo);

    // Create combinations
    let strings = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < indices.length - 2; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
            for (let k = j + 1; i < indices.length; i++) {
                let c1 = toChar(indices[i])
                let c2 = toChar(indices[j])
                let c3 = toChar(indices[k]);
                strings.push(
                    c1 + c2 + c3,
                    c1 + c3 + c2,
                    c2 + c1 + c3,
                    c2 + c3 + c1,
                    c3 + c2 + c1,
                    c3 + c1 + c3,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
// Permutes all 3
function fCombination2(combo) {
    let sorted = createSorted(combo);
    let firstIndices = [];
    let restIndices = [];
    getIndices(sorted, firstIndices, combo);
    getIndices(sorted, restIndices, combo);
    getIndices(sorted, restIndices, combo);

    // Create combinations
    let strings = [];
    firstIndices.forEach(k => {
        let arr = restIndices;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (var j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                let c1 = toChar(k)
                let c2 = toChar(arr[i])
                let c3 = toChar(arr[j])
                strings.push(
                    c1 + c2 + c3,
                    c1 + c3 + c2,
                );
            }
        }
    });
    return strings;
}

//   Test
  console.log(fCombination1([1, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3]));
  console.log(fCombination1([1,2,15,14,12,10]));
  console.log(fCombination1([1,2,15,14,14,10]));
  console.log(fCombination1([1,2,15,14,13,13]));

  console.log(fCombination2([1, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3]));
  console.log(fCombination2([1,2,15,14,12,10]));
  console.log(fCombination2([1,2,15,14,14,10]));
  console.log(fCombination2([1,2,15,14,13,13]));
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the original question, I have corrected the question so it is better understood.  The goal is to get the combinations based on the first three largest values of the Array.